# Rails: select records with maximum date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In my app users can save sales reports for given dates. What I want to do now is to query the database and select only the latest sales reports (all those reports that have the maximum date in my table).

I know how to sort all reports by date and to select the one with the highest date - however I don't know how to retrieve multiple reports with the highest date.

How can I achieve that? I'm using Postgres.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SalesReport.where(date: SalesReport.maximum('date'))
```

**EDIT:** Just to bring visibility to @muistooshort's comment below, you can reduce the two queries to a single query (with a subselect), using the following form:

```
SalesReport.where(date: SalesReport.select('MAX(date)'))
```

If there is a lot of latency between your web host and your database host, this could halve execution times. It is almost always the preferred form.

Comment: That's it! Perfect! Thx a lot!

Comment: If you `SalesReport.where(:date => SalesReport.select('max(date)'))` ActiveRecord use a subquery instead of two queries. Probably isn't worth worrying about in cases like this though.

Comment: How many SQL queries is this going to make? `SalesReport.where(date: SalesReport.select('MAX(date)'))
`

Comment: @victorhazbun just one

Answer (score 5):

You can get the maximum date to search for matching reports:

```
max_date = Report.maximum('date')
reports = Report.where(date: max_date)
```